# Why does this syntax of $ for jQuery and Backbone.js work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

For example, `demo_view` is an instance of `Backbone.View`, from [this tutorial](http://backbone.codeschool.com/levels/3), this usage is recommended..

```
demo_view.$el.html()
```

As I understood, `$` in jQuery is a function that should be used with parentheses, e.g. -> `$("#id")`, but why it can be used in `demo_view.$el` without a parentheses? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: You've gotten some good answers, so this is just a fun tidbit to go with them. Paste this into the JavaScript console and see what happens: `var π = Math.PI; alert(π);` (Note that I'm not recommending that you use characters like this as variable names.)

Answer (score 3):

It's also a symbol which can be used to name a simple variable, it belongs to the set of allowed characters for naming variables in javascript.

In jQuery, $ is used to name a function (it's a shorthand for the variable `jQuery` actually) but they could have chosen any letter of the alphabet or any other valid variable name.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why they use `$el` is to denote that the el element is a jquery object. It is purely for readability. Appending '$' before a variable identifier is kind of like a notation that denotes that the variable is a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$` and `_` are valid symbols that can be used in variable names and property names. The convention by some develoepers is to use `$` to indicate that the property or variable is a jQuery object and not some ordinary object or value. Thus you can readily tell that it is a jQuery object and use jQuery methods without doubt.